# Pickerview value on uitabelview cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uipickerview

In my application i have implement the functionality as follows,Tabelview cell contains two button on click it shows the picker view,When i select picker value its not reflecting on uitabelview corresponding cell.label, here the code.

Tableview cell

```
    if(tableView.tag==25)
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ordercel";
        ordercel *cell = (ordercel *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ordercel" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.pimg.image=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.sizlb.text=@"45";
        cell.qtylb.text=[qtyary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl1];

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.tag = indexPath.row+2000;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(130, 20 , 70, 35);
        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell addSubview:button];

        UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button1.tag = indexPath.row+4000;
        [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(sizPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        button1.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        button1.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
        button1.frame = CGRectMake(230, 20 , 70, 35);
        [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell addSubview:button1];
        return cell;
    }
```

Button method

```
-(void)BtnPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self createActionSheet];
    pickerType = @"qtypicker";
    UIPickerView *chPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
    chPicker.tag=sender.tag-2000;
    chPicker.dataSource = self;
    chPicker.delegate = self;
    chPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [actionSheet addSubview:chPicker];
}
```

Picker view code

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
 }

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
    if ([pickerType isEqualToString:@"qtypicker"])
    {
        counti = [array count];
    }
    if ([pickerType isEqualToString:@"sizepicker"])
    {
        counti = [array1 count];
    }
    return counti;
}

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSString *string;
    if ([pickerType isEqualToString:@"qtypicker"])
    {
        string = [array objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    if ([pickerType isEqualToString:@"sizepicker"])
    {
        string = [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    return string;
    }
    - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component      {
    return 300;
    }

    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    UITableViewCell *owningCell = (UITableViewCell*)[thePickerView superview];
    NSIndexPath *pathToCell = [tabvu indexPathForCell:owningCell];
    int index1=thePickerView.tag;//= thePickerView.tag-2000;
    if ([pickerType isEqualToString:@"qtypicker"])
    {
         UILabel *obj=((UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:index1+1000]);
         obj.text = [array objectAtIndex:row];
        [qtyary addObject:obj.text];
        [tabvu reloadData];
    }
    if ([pickerType isEqualToString:@"sizepicker"])
    {

    }
    }
```

How to get the selected picker value on selected cell.What change should i made in my code?Please help me to sort it out

Comment: Have you connected data source and delegate properly ?

Comment: why is your picker height 0? try putting a height on the picker

Comment: @Bhargavi Yes i have connected

Answer (score 0):

Your code is difficult to read. But this should be the way.

```
pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow
```

method update the array object `[qtyary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`. Then call `[tableView reloadData];` This will update your `cell.qtylb.text`. For other label also you need a array which you will update. I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

try changing line in didSelectRow

```
UITableViewCell *owningCell = (UITableViewCell*)[thePickerView superview];
```

to

```
ordercel *owningCell = (ordercel*)[thePickerView superview];
```

If you have custom cell that you are using to put button on.Then you should take cell instance of your custom cell not UITableViewCell.

And try printing log in this condition

```
    if ([pickerType isEqualToString:@"qtypicker"])
{
     UILabel *obj=((UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:index1+1000]);
     obj.text = [array objectAtIndex:row];
    [qtyary addObject:obj.text];
    [tabvu reloadData];
}
```

what object it is returning.Apply NSLog to obj.